# Question about Light Clocks (Intro Relativity)

Tags: special-relativity

When introducing relativity, people often begin by explaining Einstein’s light clock experiment.

A video explains the concept of a light clock: A unit of time is represented by the photon hitting the top of a clock (shaped like a tube with a mirror on top and on the bottom) and then being reflected down. When the clock moves, the photon appears to go more slowly because it is actually going on a diagonal line. Here is a great picture (a screenshot from the video) that explains this idea!
[image: Photon in a moving light clock]

Unfortunately, I don’t understand at all. Wouldn’t the photon hit the walls of the tube/clock and not even reach the top of the clock?

Here is the link to the video referenced in this question: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=js1myWkrv8Q

Thank you very much!

Comment: why would the photon hit the side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clock is moving with the photon (it's just not shown in that picture as too many clocks would make it messy).

So for every dashed vertical line imagine the clock centered around the photon.

Some further animations [here](https://www.einstein-online.info/en/spotlight/light-clocks-time-dilation/) and [here](https://galileoandeinstein.phys.virginia.edu/more_stuff/Applets/Lightclock/home.html) if that helps.

Comment: Thank you - these are excellent animations. You cleared most of my confusion. Although to some extent I am still confused about the idea of the light clock moving along with the photon. Why don’t you have the situation with a person on a train moving at constant speed and tossing a ball in the air vertically (i.e., why does the photon in a light clock lose some of its speed if it is actually bouncing vertically at every point?)

Comment: @Yelena don't worry, most people get confused by Relativity at some point :)  The photon doesn't loose any speed, it can only ever travel at the one speed c and it is doing this along the diagonal line.  The trick is understanding that someone moving along with the bouncing photon (in the light clock) won't see its horizontal speed (just like if you're tossing a ball on a train, you don't notice it's sideways motion).

Comment: Thank you so much! That really helps. Something that is still confusing is that with Newton’s General Relativity we learned that motion at a constant speed “acts” like rest. So the idea is the vertical motion does not change but the horizontal motion does - and it is this horizontal motion that creates the time dilation / length contraction?

Comment: In some regards yes.  If you consider that nothing can travel faster than light, but if something (a spaceship) is traveling close to light speed horizontally, then on that spaceship, where they don't notice their horizontal speed, their (non-horizontal speed) can't be much (it can't add up to be greater than the speed of light).  The tricky bit is that everything is equally slowed (similar to the light clock) so they don't notice the time dilation either, only a stationary observer will see the time dilation.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it is tricky, and I guess I’ll have to mull it over - but thanks to these great explanations, everything is so much clearer! I really appreciate it.